# Meteor methods middleware authorization

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to implement authorization in Meteor 1.5 methods.
Those methods will be called by some client through HTTP endpoints, not by the application itself.

Authorization requires handling different roles, like admin, moderator (for that I'm using `alanning:roles` package).
For authorizing HTTP requests I'm using `dispatch:run-as-user` package.

Is there a proper way to implement some kind of middleware that would work the same for each method, by checking if current user has proper role to call the method?

Or is there a better approach to authorize Meteor methods?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a proper way to implement some kind of middleware that would work the same for each method, by checking if current user has proper role to call the method?

Yes, there's a complicated way to declare methods that allows this behavior. See https://guide.meteor.com/methods.html.

This will be over-engineered for your needs. The best middleware for authorizing calls inside methods is used by calling `this.userId` inside your method body, and represents the most elegant solution in the `meteor` universe. Use `alanning:roles` as usual inside each method body. Then, to achieve:

> client through HTTP endpoints

Use a package like `cfs:http-methods` to achieve this using the `Accounts` package for authorization. The client HTTP calls expect a `?token` query parameter whose value is equal to `Accounts._storedLoginToken()`.